# Google Sheets MID formula outputs weird value not compatible with IF function

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets

In Google Sheets, the `MID` formula seems to output a weird value type that doesn't work well with comparison functions, namely `IF`. This issue also applies to `LEFT` and `RIGHT` functions.

Below, The Row 1 shows the function in each cell, Row 2 shows the column names, and Row 3 shows the values.

Each cell with a number is of type **Custom Number Format: 123**

```
 SOURCE      "=IF($A2>123,$A2-1,$A2)"   "=MID($A2,1,3)" "=IF($C2>123,$C2-1,$C2)"

 Col A        Col B                      Col C            Col D
 ---------------------------------------------------------------
 123          123                        123              122
```

The expected output from the `IF` check in `Col D` on the `MID` output is `123`, yet it's outputting `122` (even though 123 is NOT greater than 123).

Even if I change the formats of each cell to **Number 1,000.12**, the `IF` check on `MID`'s output is wrong.

Why is this?

---

**EDIT**: My hunch is that `MID` `LEFT` and `RIGHT` accept `string` inputs and passing in a number to substring somehow still works in output, but operating on the output gets wonky?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its because **C2** is considered as `Plain text` from **D2**, therefore, `MID` needs to be wrapped in `VALUE` like:

```
=VALUE(MID($A2,1,3))
```

[image: 0]

---

[image: 0]

Comment: It's considered as plaintext even after setting the value type on the cell?

Comment: setting up a format with `123` button is in some cases only visual thing.